# Using system calls in C writing padded hex

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

Hey so i'm fairly new to C itself and very new to using system calls in C but i have to use it for an assignment so i was trying to practicing reading and writing to and from a file. The read works fine but for some reason the write is doing weird things. its writing to the file some kind of padded hex representation of the number i want to write to the file. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
buffer= 10;
if (write(file, &buffer,sizeof(int)) < sizeof(int)) {
    printf("Error in writing\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

when i run this it puts that in the file but when i printout the number itself it prints the correct number

> `0a00 0000`

Comment: How do you examine the file? How do you check what is written? How do you open the file? And what does this have to do with C# or C++?

Comment: What do you want to write to the file? If you want to write the number 10 to the file, you have to convert it into a string first.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(int)` is 4 bytes (evidently in your environment), which is 32-bits and can be represented by 8 hexadecimal digits, which is what you're seeing in the file.

You're apparently on a [Little Endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) machine so the least significant byte is written first. On a big endian machine you would see 0000 000a in the file instead.

Comment: but what I want to be written to the file is the decimal representation not the hex. Do i have to manually convert it to decimal or something ?

Comment: @JoshRoberts If you want to be able to open the file in notepad or whatever your text editor of choice is and see "10" in there, you'll have to write the ASCII (or unicode, again depending on text editor) values of the digits in there. Using the code you have (but with an 8-bit `char` type instead of `int`, try writing the values 49 (ASCII code for '1') followed by 48 (ASCII code for '0'). Then when you open the file in a text editor you'll see "10". Of course, in the hex editor or whatever you used to see 0a00 0000, you'll see 3130. (the hexadecimal of the 2 8-bit integers 49 and 48)

Comment: @JoshRoberts You could pull the same trick with a single `short` value (16 bits) of 12337 (0x3031 hex). Again, on your little endian machine it would reverse the bytes and write the byte 49 decimal followed by 48 decimal to the file and your text editor would show "10".

Comment: @JoshRoberts Keep in mind that the write() function is simply dumping bits to the file. In the case of 0x3031 it would be writing 00110000 00110001. How you interpret that is up to you. A text editor will read that and show you the ASCII representation of those 2 bytes (the characters 1 and 0). Or you can read it as the decimal value 12337. Or whatever your heart desires. It's important to remember there's a difference between the value itself and a representation of that value.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(int)` is 32 bits, so 4 bytes. That means 4 sets of two hex values. Does that make sense? So it should be padding it since you are writing 4 bytes worth.

Answer (score 0):

Use snprintf

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
    int file = creat("afile.txt",S_IRWXU);
    int buffer= 10;
    char sbuffer[10];
    snprintf(sbuffer,sizeof(sbuffer),"%d",buffer);
    if (write(file, &sbuffer,strlen(sbuffer)) < strlen(sbuffer)) {
        printf("Error in writing\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    close(file);
}
```